# what happens in the registry when installing with an MSI in Windows 7?

Tags: .net, windows-7, installation, registry, windows-installer

When installing a program in Windows 7 (all windows versions would be awesome to know about...but Windows 7 will suffice for now) with an MSI...


-What & where are the changes made in the registry on installation and how do all of those changes relate to one another?


-How can I find **ALL** of the data relating to a given installation should I ever need it, do I have to go through the registry to obtain this data or is there another more efficient or more appropriate way to access the data?

Comment: It is an implementation detail for MSI.  It maintains keys so it can properly re-install, update and uninstall apps.  Which does beg the question, why is this important to you?  Just curiosity or are you trying to solve an actual problem?  You can observe the keys being read and written with SysInternals' ProcMon utility if you are curious.

Comment: @HansPassant My reasons are that I need to find out if an application is installed and what the version of an installed application is. Another reason is general curiosity and for future reference...hence my not asking only how to find the current version installed.

Comment: You can only find data MSI knows about, not 'ALL' data. Any custom actions, MSI doesn't know changes - you can only find that by monitoring changes or asking developer. They're going "outside" MSI for that. Bobs answer is best for 'what MSI knows'

Comment: @saschabeaumont Yes, I can only find data that MSI knows about...but where can I find that data in the registry is my question not how/where do I get it from an MSI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been playing with the registry and installations to see what I can come up with. **If anyone can elaborate further on my answer or make any corrections, it would be greatly appreciated as this answer only comes from observation and not from any official source.** I've made some tables describing what I've found as seen in the image below. Also, for accessing the information needed (IE, the ProductName or ProductCode properties of an MSI) I've come across WIX (http://wixtoolset.org/) and am using Micrsoft.Deployment.Installer.dll as well as other libraries included with WIX as they are pretty dang sweet.


I don't know the official terms for all of the keys & codes that I reference here...so don't be surprised if it seems like I made them up because of what they seem to designate, because I did.


**Update:** I just found some more useful info in the MSI docs that might be appreciated here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372105(v=vs.85).aspx


[image: Analysis of windows 7 registry with respect to installations performed by an MSI]

Comment: It still remains sound advice to avoid directly poking at your system's internal organs by not relying on these implementation details, even if they don't look like they'll change in a while.

Comment: @BoltClock I would agree...but when you're stuck with no other way, this comes in handy.

Answer (score 2):

Use the MSI API, such as the [MsiGetProductInfoEx function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370131%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The registry data is mostly undocumented because it's an implementation detail, as Hans mentions.

Answer (score 0):

Using MsiGetProductInfoEx (and possibly MsiEnumProductsEx) is the recommended programmatic method to get information about installed products. Using this approach, you could then compare changes to the ProductCode, ProductVersion, and package code (i.e. Revision Number Summary property) values. A small update to the application however could leave the ProductCode and ProductVersion unchanged. A typical small update changes only one or two files or a registry key, and in this case the package code should also be changed. However, a product shipped with a language transform might have the same package code as the product without the tranform.

If you are developing your own Windows Installer package that needs to determine whether the user has already installed a version of the application, you can use the Windows Installer service to search for a specific file or directory during your application's installation.  This approach requires populating the appropriate tables in the Windows installer database and the msi should run the AppSearch Action. This method is describe in Microsoft's Windows Installer documentation published here:

[Searching for Existing Applications, Files, Registry Entries or .ini File Entries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371564%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)