# What happens when we install or uninstall a .msi or .exe package?

Tags: windows, installation, uninstallation

I want to know the internal details. How registries are changed? How after installation ,Programs and Features is able to detect uninstall file for uninstall? How files are created. It will be better if you can give some example please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please refer to : https://www.raymond.cc/blog/tracking-registry-and-files-changes-when-installing-software-in-windows/  
 above will give : to Track Registry and File Changes by Comparing Before and After Snapshots

About MSI :MSI is an installer package file format used by Windows. Its name comes from the program’s original title, Microsoft Installer, which has since changed to Windows Installer. MSI files are used for installation, storage, and removal of programs. The files are contained in a package, which is used with the program’s client-side installer service, an .EXE file, to open and install the program.

u can check the previous question asked in stackoverflow [what happens in the registry when installing with an MSI in Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737352/what-happens-in-the-registry-when-installing-with-an-msi-in-windows-7)

Comment: Thanks Annadate. This helped a little. I found a UninstallString in HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\xxx\{Some hexadecimal}. It was like misexec.exe /X{hexadecimal}. How this is able to identify uninstall file in the installation directory?

Comment: @Embydextrous
for example hex is : **"{893F27E6-D6BE-4B9F-80E6-0ADA694A31A8}" = Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Common Files**
else even wen u opn that any hex folder of regedit- u can get that hex is associated to 'wat' by 'display name' ... when we uninstall any soft. it do check for corresponding hex or 'key'. uninstaller scans registry with 'wat' corresponding it wants to uninstall.

Comment: @Anandate okay.. so if i run **"msiexec \X{893F27E6-D6BE-4B9F-80E6-0ADA694A31A8}"** it would actually find the uninstaller.exe file(if any) and would obtain this information from corresponding registry. And if I have added some read protection on this registry then I guess it will end up with some exception. Am I right? 
Can u please explain uninstall process in brief? Also if registry is read protected will uninstall.exe run properly if I launch it directly?

Comment: evn m not totally knwn to uninstalling process .. bt let me clear u a fact that u r misleading - in regedit it stores call and predefined parameters. like wat we have a kind of function with predefined stratergies. hence wen we uninstall x  system will search associated info in its registry for the uninstall optns.

Comment: I know this. Actually I got the exact answers for what I am searching from team discussion at my office. But, your answer was a great start for me. I got a lot of understanding regarding this and basically it acted as a propeller. Thanks for the time!